# IllegalArgumentException when injecting a seam component

Tags: seam2

I am trying to migrate an application which uses seam 2.1.2, from JBoss 5.2 to JBoss 6.4 EAP. I added all the seam dependent libraries as maven dependencies and now I have the application deploying without any errors and the seam context seems to be created successfully (and some of the flows are working as expected).

I stumbled upon an issue and I hope that someone can help with an advise.

My EAR has the following structure:

```
myapp.ear
|
|--- warpck.war
|
|--- ejb.jar
|
|--- client1.jar
|
|--- client2.jar
|
|--- commons.jar
|
|--- loggers.jar
```

In the client1.jar I have the following java bean defined:

```
@Name(CustomClient.NAME)
@AutoCreate
public class CustomClientImpl implements CustomClient {
...  
}
```

The CustomClient interface looks like this:

```
public interface CustomClient extends GeneratedSoapClients {

    String NAME = "customClient";

}
```

During the deployment I have the following log:

```
09:14:44,574 INFO  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) Component: customClient, scope: EVENT, type: JAVA_BEAN, class: myapp.client.impl.CustomClientImpl
```

...so I assume that the component is registered correctly in the seam context.

The problem is when I try to inject this component into one of the classes form the ejb.jar package. I get the following error:

```
09:14:49,319 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component CustomAdapterWs for method public myapp.webservice.v5.CustomResponse myapp.webservice.impl.CustomAdapterWs.customInformation(myapp.webservice.v5.CustomInformation): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not set field value: CustomAdapterController.customClient

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not set field value: CustomAdapterController.customClient
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.setFieldValue(Component.java:1927) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.access$600(Component.java:126) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component$BijectedField.set(Component.java:2940) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.injectAttributes(Component.java:1736) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.inject(Component.java:1554) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185) [jboss-seam-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not set field value by reflection: CustomAdapterController.customClient on: myapp.controller.CustomAdapterController with value: class myapp.client.impl.CustomClientImpl_$$_javassist_seam_2



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set myapp.client.CustomClient field myapp.controller.CustomAdapterController.customClient to myapp.client.impl.CustomClientImpl_$$_javassist_seam_2
```

The CustomAdapterController:

```
@Name(CustomAdapterController.NAME)
@AutoCreate
public class CustomAdapterController {

    public static final String NAME = "CustomAdapterController";

    @In(value = CustomClient.NAME)
    private CustomClient customClient;
```

The javassist dependency that I use (it's added in the EAR pom):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

The jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.javassist" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="warpck.war">
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>

<sub-deployment name="ejb.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="client1.jar"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

All the components that are defined in the ejb.jar are injected correctly. The issue appears each time I try to inject a bean which is defined in a differenect package. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

you can't unless you use this version of seam

[Seam 2.2.3](https://github.com/omidp/seam)

and this is [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://github.com/omidp/playground/blob/master/projectTemplate/omidbiz-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml)